# Comma after adverb in quote tag?

Tags: commas, adverbs, quotes

Do you add a comma after an adverb in a dialog sentence, such as

> "Stop it!" she yelled, loudly.

Should there be a comma after *yelled*?

Comment: "Not unless there were some rhetorical purpose," I countered politely.

Answer (score 1):

- If you want to emphasize mainly that she yelled (and it just *happened to be* loud) -- no comma.
- If you want to emphasize that her yelling was [LOUD](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/609/02/) -- use the comma.